# I get undefined value when I make a request to the MongoDB database using the mongodb engine in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using ExpressJS and MongoDB to create a blog for myself. I have created a mini library with the **mongodb module** to request the MongoDB database.

Here is the library:

```
'use strict'

const { MongoClient, ObjectId } = require('mongodb')
const { config } = require('../config')

const USER = encodeURIComponent(config.mongodb.user)
const PASS = encodeURIComponent(config.mongodb.pass)
const NAME = config.mongodb.name
const HOST = config.mongodb.host

const URL = `mongodb+srv://${USER}:${PASS}@${HOST}/${NAME}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
const OPTIONS = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}

class MongoLib {
  constructor () {
    this.client = new MongoClient(URL, OPTIONS)
    this.name = NAME
  }

  connect () {
    if (!MongoLib.connection) {
      MongoLib.connection = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.client.connect(err => {
          if (err) reject(err)
          console.log('Connected successfully to MongoDB.')
          resolve(this.client.db(this.name))
        })
      })
    }

    return MongoLib.connection
  }

  getAll (collection, query) {
    return this.connect().then(db => {
      return db.collection(collection).find({ query }).toArray()
    })
  }

  get (collection, id) {
    return this.connect().then(db => {
      return db.collection(collection).findOne({ _id: ObjectId(id) })
    })
  }

  create (collection, data) {
    return this.connect().then(db => {
      return db.collection(collection).insertOne(data)
    }).then(result => result.insertedId)
  }

  update (collection, id, data) {
    return this.connect().then(db => {
      return db.collection(collection).updateOne({ _id: ObjectId(id) }, { $set: data }, { upsert: true })
    }).then(result => result.upsertedId || id)
  }

  delete (collection, id) {
    return this.connect().then(db => {
      return db.collection(collection).deleteOne({ _id: ObjectId(id) })
    }).then(() => id)
  }
}

module.exports = MongoLib
```

The database is connecting correctly because I have a seed that injects data into the database using the create method of the library that you just saw.

In the service layer, I create a class with a method called **getUser**, which will call the getAll method of the MongoDB library, to which we pass a query so that it looks for the user.

```
'use strict'

const MongoLib = require('../lib/mongo')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

class UsersService {
  constructor () {
    this.collection = 'users'
    this.mongoDB = new MongoLib()
  }

  async getUser ({ email }) {
    // { email } is getted by basic authentication as a "username" to login
    // I am receiving this data perfectly
    const [user] = await this.mongoDB.getAll(this.collection, { email })
    // But the problem start here, the value of user is undefined
    return user
  }

  async createUser ({ user }) {
    const { name, email, password } = user
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10)

    const createUserId = await this.mongoDB.create(this.collection, {
      name,
      email,
      password: hashedPassword
    })

    return createUserId
  }
}

module.exports = UsersService
```

The problem here is that the user value is undefined. I don't understand why it causes conflict. I'm using async-await to wait for the database request to finish, and the data is in the database correctly.

Does anyone have an idea about this error? If more information needs it, please let me know.

Comment: Try using `get` method instead of the `getAll` - you are trying to read one user.

Comment: @prasad_ that's true, but I want the user with a specified email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suspect your query is wrong, you are sending { { email: email } } to mongodb

```
  getAll (collection, query) {
    return this.connect().then(db => {
      return db.collection(collection).find(query).toArray()
    })
  }
```